# How to change the frame a UIButton after it has been created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

In my ViewDidLoad I create a UIButton programmatically and assign it the tag 1.

Later on I use the code:
       UIButton* otherButton = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
Now this button works perfectly with code, changing the frame etc!
Except I get the warning: 
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIButton *' from 'UIView *'

Is there a better way to find the button, or should I just ignore the error?

Comment: The title and the content of your question are unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it:

```
UIButton* myButton = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];`
```

You could also be a little more defensive and check:

```
UIView* v = [self.view viewWithTag:1];
UIButton* myButton = [v isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]] ? (UIButton*)v : nil;
NSAssert(myButton == v, @"View with tag 1 was not a UIButton");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly cast the `UIView` into a `UIButton` like this.

```
 UIButton* otherButton = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```